# how to update an object without sending the complete json of the entity

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, crud

I am currently using "Spring boot".

Requirement is to make an **endpoint to update an entity such as a user**, but I do not want to send all the "Json" of the object because it has 4 related tables and grows a lot in size.

Is it possible to send selected fields to update instead whole "json" of the object?

Comment: Hi @Carlos It is possible, but it would be great to answer with context as well as if you post code you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi @Carlos could you please show us the controller method used to expose the response.?

Comment: You could send only those fields which you want to update. But in java code you have to handle missing/null values, if there is any restriction on DB side

Answer (score 0):

You could create an API with **HTTP PATCH** method and can send the fields which need to be updated.

> When we need to replace an existing Resource entirely, they can use
>   PUT. When we are doing a partial update, we can use HTTP PATCH.

Answer (score 0):

If you referring to update the database with partial information you can use: `@DynamicUpdate(HibernateConfig.dynamicUpdate)` on the entity which only updates changed fields.
This may cause a degradation in performance because the `updates` to the DB uses different statements which make it hard on the DB itself to cache the execution plans.